# How to call incremented variable defined in one page to another in php

Tags: php

Ok. This might seem duplicate to few people, but its not :)

Here's the question

page-1.php

```
$link = 'page-2.php'
$i = 0;
    foreach( $data as $row ){
$i++;   
$id = $i; 
 echo "
<tr>
<td><a href='".$link."'>{$row['name']}</a></td>
</tr>"; 
}
```

page-2.php

```
if (isset($_GET[$id])) {
    if ($id == '0')
     $offset = '0';
    else if ($id == '1')
     $offset = '1';
    else if ($id == '2')
     $offset = '2';
    else if ($id == '3')
     $offset = '3'; 
   }

$name = $global[$offset]['name'];
```

I keep getting these errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: id
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: offset

How to solve this, so that $offset value is aligned to the $id value in way that when $id = '0', $offset = '0' and so on.

Rgds..

Comment: What sthe idea behind you using this `if (isset($_GET[$id]))`. because there is no request pass to second page. so why you used GET Request ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the variable in the link to the next page:

```
<td><a href="page-2.php?varname=<?php echo $var_value ?>">Page2</a></td>
```

This will create a GET variable.

And then on page two:

```
//Using GET
$var_value = $_GET['varname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not send data like that.. instead Use session to send data from one page to another.
You can set session variable by starting the session as session_start();
Then you can set session variable as:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Hope it helps!